Dealing with DI lifecycles & cached data in a service class
I have a component in my Angular 11 app that uses a specific service class to request address information from a REST API. This service class caches a few observables in a field that relay the API response. This essentially allows multiple dependencies within a component to all get the response object from the API without making multiple redundant API requests.
The issue is that I need this service object to be recreated each time users navigate to the page. Unfortunately, I've been unable to get the desired lifecycle for my service class, and as a result, the cached observables live too long, resulting in my app operating on stale API data over time. Example code is below.
Service Class:
@Injectable()
export class ScopedAddressDS {
  constructor(private readonly addressDS: AddressDS) {}

  private readonly addressCache = new Map<number, Observable<Address>>();

  public observeAddress(clientId: number): Observable<Address> {
    if (!this.addressCache.has(clientId)) {
      this.addressCache.set(clientId, from(this.addressDS.getAddress({id: clientId})).pipe(shareReplay(1)));
    }

    return this.addressCache.get(clientId);
  }
}

Registrations (at the component module.ts level):
const routes: Routes = [{
  path: '',
  component: ItemDetailsComponent,
  data: {
    breadcrumb: 'Item Details'
  }
}];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(routes),
    // others...
  ],
  declarations: [
    ItemDetailsComponent,
    // others...
  ],
  providers: [
    ScopedAddressDS,
    // others...
  ],
})
export class ItemsDetailsModule {}

And an example of how the component injects the service class (note that this class has other dependencies, which they themselves also depend on the same service class; this is how the data gets relayed/shared):
@Component({
  selector: 'item-details',
  templateUrl: './item-details.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./item-details.component.scss'],
  providers: [BreadcrumbsService],
})
export class ItemDetailsComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  constructor(
    private scopedAddressDS: ScopedAddressDS
    // etc...
  ) {
  }
}

One potential solution I found while doing research is that it's possible for a route to have providers but since my application is stuck in Angular 11 (for now), that doesn't seem to be an option to me.
Assuming my overall design and reliance on DI isn't flawed, how can I structure my type registrations so that I get the desired lifetime scope (that is, that my ScopedAddressDS instances get re-created each time the user navigates to the page that depends on it)?

You can use event of Router, to reset the cache, on navigation end. Another way is to call the reset on destroy of components, but this first approach is more generic.
I use the map clear method to empty the cache.
@Injectable()
export class ScopedAddressDS {
  private sub: Subscription = new Subscription();

  private readonly addressCache = new Map<number, Observable<Address>>();

  public observeAddress(clientId: number): Observable<Address> {
    if (!this.addressCache.has(clientId)) {
      this.addressCache.set(
        clientId,
        from(this.addressDS.getAddress({ id: clientId })).pipe(shareReplay(1))
      );
    }

    return this.addressCache.get(clientId);
  }

  constructor(private router: Router, private readonly addressDS: AddressDS) {
    this.sub.add(
      this.router.events
        .pipe(filter((e): e is NavigationEnd => e instanceof NavigationEnd))
        .subscribe(() => {
          this.addressCache.clear();
        })
    );
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.sub.unsubscribe();
  }
}


I get a couple of errors with this solution. Webstorm tells me I can't have multiple constructors, it also doesn't know what this.firstChildData$ is, or this.router. What am I missing?

@void.pointer I made a mistake please check now

I still see multiple constructors. Should that work and I have something wrong with my IDE?

@void.pointer sorry, for mistakes, check now

Thanks for the fixes, I still get TS2339: Property router does not exist on type ScopedAddressDS

@void.pointer updated

Thanks, this solution appears to be functional. The only weirdness I noticed is that the cache is cleared not only when leaving the relevant page, but when entering it too. However, the clear happens before the observeAddress() method is called, so it works out. Understanding this behavior would be valuable, but there doesn't seem to be an issue with it.

@void.pointer When we navigate the cache is cleared, a navigation involves NavigationStart and NavigationEnd I think taht is why you are getting this issue.
